# Android saving google map state in fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am using google map in fragment . Map loads first time perfectly but when I tried to come back to fragment that contains google map  from another fragment it crashes with the following error .

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment
```

Here is the code for initializing the fragment

```
SupportMapFragment fragment
```

And in `onCreateView`

```
  fragment = (SupportMapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
  fragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

And the code for layout

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

In order to resolve the issue, I removed the map fragment in `onPause` like this

```
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .remove(fragment).commit();
```

But the problem is if I do this google map reloads every time. It redraws the marker. What I want is while I am navigating through other fragment, I want to save the google map state .

Comment: Please post of Fragment code

Comment: @AjayShrestha thanks, but  I have already posted. Which Fragment code are you talking about ?

Comment: any more information about the exception when it crash?

Comment: @AssIstne no, it just crash and in logcat I have found the message I posted

Comment: "come back to fragment that contains google map from another fragment", how do you go to another fragment? By replacing the fragment contains map? When you leave the map-fragment, is it destroyed?

Comment: @AssIstne , I have an Acitvity, which has couple of fragment. One of this contains google map . When I leave the fragment that contains google map , it isn't destroyed .

Comment: so what method do you call to change the fragment? replace? hide? you should post those codes of the activity.

Comment: @AssIstne  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.mainFragmentContainer, fragment, "tag")
                        .commit();

Comment: if you use the replace method, the map-fragment will be detached from the activity. Try hide method to avoid that. And check the fragment.getMapAsync(this); Is it ok to async in the onCreateView?

Answer (score -1):

in fact, you can also use FrameLayout inside xml file and then add fragment into it. And then in your Activity class,

```
SupportMapFragment f = (SupportMapFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
if(f != null ){
  //remove fragment
  //add fragment 
}
```

Hope it helps